# Heatmap with different colors for each row

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn, heatmap

I am trying to build a heatmap with seaborn that each row of the 'table' get a different color range. Example:
A: yellow
B: blue
C: green
D: red

must be in the same table for comparing the own row along the year and different rows in the same month. Is my question clear, thanks so much?

I only could plot the heatmap comparing all the table:

[image]

```
d = {'jan': [44, 2, 3, 4],
'feb': [33, 4, 6, 8],
'mar': [50, 10, 15, 20],
'abr': [11, 12, 13, 14],
'mai': [3, 40, 6, 60],
'jun': [40, 8, 12, 16]}

idx = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']

df = pd.DataFrame(d, index = idx)

sns.heatmap(df, annot = True, cmap = 'Blues')
plt.yticks(rotation = 0)
```

That is what i trying to plot. Made with google sheets:

[image]

Comment: Please format your code samples as code for clarity

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you to do one plot per line and put them into a plt subplot:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

d = {'jan': [44, 2, 3, 4], 'feb': [33, 4, 6, 8], 'mar': [50, 10, 15, 20], 'abr': [11, 12, 13, 14], 'mai': [3, 40, 6, 60], 'jun': [40, 8, 12, 16]}

idx = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']

df = pd.DataFrame(d, index = idx)
cm = ['Blues', 'Reds', 'Greens', 'Purples']
f, axs = plt.subplots(4, 1, gridspec_kw={'hspace': 0})

counter = 0
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    sns.heatmap(np.array([row.values]), yticklabels=[idx[counter]], xticklabels=df.columns, annot=True, fmt='.2f', ax=axs[counter], cmap=cm[counter], cbar=False)
    counter += 1

plt.show()
```

**Output :**

[image]

Comment: Woooow. Thanks so muuuuuch... 

The original dataframe the indexes length are much longer... so, I just looked for to see how iterate the indexes...

I added for ax in fig.axes:
    plt.sca(ax)
    plt.yticks(rotation = 0)

Again, thank so much